# Как узнать, что в 1С произошла ошибка?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Мне нужно идентифицировать если произошла ошибка в программе 1с. Например если служба выключена, то 1с выдаст ошибку (определенное окно). Как я могу это сделать?

В данный момент это работает так: С помощью библиотеки OpenCV по определенным шаблонам распознается печатный текст и таким способом идентифицируется суть ошибки. Но это не всегда работает. Кто что может подсказать, или дать почитать?

Comment: Программа, печатный текст, OpenCV, сервис, ошибки - вы меня запутали. Что вам конкретно надо сделать при помощи C#, что вы пытались сделать и что не получилось?

Comment: @tym32167 У меня все получилось, и работает. Проблема в том, что не всегда. Работает так: например на компьютере-клиенте появляется ошибка в 1с, с помощью библиотеки OpenCV распознается текст ошибки (по шаблону), и передается инфа на сервер, который обрабатывает и передает данную ошибку другому клиенту(админу). Проблема в том, что OpenCV распознает ошибку по скрину, т е если он не успеет сделать скрин ошибки, то ошибка не будет распознана и останется. Возможно это сделать какими-либо другими средствами?

Comment: А зачем выключать службу от которой работа зависит? И вы боретесь не с причиной, а с последствиями.

Comment: @ГеннадийП это был пример. И да, они иногда вырубаются. Наглядный пример. Блокируется база после плохого обмена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, Вам предстоит знакомство с WinAPI, а конкретно с функцией [findwindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow).

Примерный алгоритм:

1. Находим окно 1С (скорее всего по имени).
2. Если оно нашлось - находим в нём окно с ошибкой.
3. Если и оно нашлось - находим в окне с ошибкой нужные элементы с текстом и [берём их значения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978879/how-do-i-read-messagebox-text-using-winapi). Тут нам пригодится Spy++ из состава студии и его [Finder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-finder-tool?view=vs-2017).

Всё это крутим бесконечно в отдельном сервисе.

Comment: Пробегал глазами еще тему WinAPI хуков, как думаете, стоит рыть в сторону их?

Comment: Спасибо большое, обязательно попробую.

Comment: О хуках я бы задумался, если бы данные нужно было как-то менять. А просто отловить факт отображения окна - тут хуки будут оверинженирингом, особенно если нет готового и привычного инструмента для использования. Впрочем, для общего развития - попробуйте и с хуками